# React - Form keeps re-rendering component while I type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This function renders a modal that shows a login form. As I type, the whole component is re-rendering, and I can only type 1 or 2 letters before it resets. I've never seen this kind of problem before.

I've tried factoring out the "opts" object, in case that was forcing the re-render. It did not change anything.

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import useApi, {IPayload} from './hooks/useApi';
import Modal from 'react-modal'
import './modal.css';
Modal.setAppElement('#root')

interface IProps {
  payload:IPayload|null,
  closeAction?:()=>void,
}

const defaultProps:IProps = {
  payload:null,
  closeAction: ()=>null,
}

function Auth(props:IProps):JSX.Element{

  const [auth, updateAuth] = useState<boolean>(false)
  const [authModalIsOpen, setAuthModal] = useState(true)
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

  const opts = {
    username: username,
    password: password,
    fail: forceLogin,
  }

  const defaultPayload:IPayload = {
      path:'notes/validateAuth/',
      method: 'GET',
      body: null,
      callback: loginAction
  }

  const [payload, setPayload] = useState(defaultPayload)
  if(props.payload!==null){

    setPayload(props.payload)
  }
  // console.log(_payload)
  // useApi(opts, payload)

  function forceLogin(){
    setAuthModal(true)
    updateAuth(false)
  }

  function closeAuthModal(){
    if(auth){ setAuthModal(false) }
  }


  function SubmitLogin(){
    setPayload(defaultPayload)
  }

  function loginAction(res:any){
    updateAuth(true)
    setAuthModal(false)
    setUsername(res.auth)
  }

  function LoginWindow(){
    return(
      <Modal
        isOpen={authModalIsOpen}
        onRequestClose={closeAuthModal}
        className='SearchModal'
        overlayClassName='SearchOverlay'
        >
        <div className="IoLinks_wrapper">
        <div className="IoLinks_incoming">
        
        <form onSubmit={(e)=>{
          e.preventDefault()
          SubmitLogin()
        }}>
            <input name='username' className='greenput_narrow' onChange={(e)=>{
              setUsername(e.target.value)
            }}/><br />
            <input type="password" name='password' className='greenput_narrow' onChange={(e)=>{
              setPassword(e.target.value)
            }}/><br />
            <button className='greenput_narrow' type="submit">Login</button>
          </form>
        
        </div>
        <div className="IoLinks_outgoing"><h1>NullDisk</h1><ul><li>Military Grade Encryption</li><li>Zettelkasten Schema</li><li>VIM Keybindings</li></ul></div>
        </div>
        </Modal>
    )
  }

  return(
    <LoginWindow/>
  )
}

Auth.defaultProps = defaultProps
export default Auth;
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `function LoginWindow()` is another component inside `function Auth(props:IProps)`. All your setStates happens in your parent component as you type. In React any change in the Parent component will trigger a re-render of child components.

If you really wanted to keep a separate child component, you had to pass all those set methods you are using in `LoginWindow` as props. Then you will have to wrap your methods that are passed into your child component in a `useCallback` so every time your parent re-renders due to the state update your functions will not regenerate as new objects. That's a path you don't need for such a small component I believe.

I don't know why you are using a component inside another component in the wrong way. Why don't you directly return your JSX like,

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import useApi, { IPayload } from './hooks/useApi';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import './modal.css';
Modal.setAppElement('#root');

interface IProps {
  payload: IPayload | null;
  closeAction?: () => void;
}

const defaultProps: IProps = {
  payload: null,
  closeAction: () => null
};

function Auth(props: IProps): JSX.Element {
  const [auth, updateAuth] = useState < boolean > false;
  const [authModalIsOpen, setAuthModal] = useState(true);
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const opts = {
    username: username,
    password: password,
    fail: forceLogin
  };

  const defaultPayload: IPayload = {
    path: 'notes/validateAuth/',
    method: 'GET',
    body: null,
    callback: loginAction
  };

  const [payload, setPayload] = useState(defaultPayload);
  if (props.payload !== null) {
    setPayload(props.payload);
  }
  // console.log(_payload)
  // useApi(opts, payload)

  function forceLogin() {
    setAuthModal(true);
    updateAuth(false);
  }

  function closeAuthModal() {
    if (auth) {
      setAuthModal(false);
    }
  }

  function SubmitLogin() {
    setPayload(defaultPayload);
  }

  function loginAction(res: any) {
    updateAuth(true);
    setAuthModal(false);
    setUsername(res.auth);
  }

  return (
    <Modal
      isOpen={authModalIsOpen}
      onRequestClose={closeAuthModal}
      className="SearchModal"
      overlayClassName="SearchOverlay"
    >
      <div className="IoLinks_wrapper">
        <div className="IoLinks_incoming">
          <form
            onSubmit={e => {
              e.preventDefault();
              SubmitLogin();
            }}
          >
            <input
              name="username"
              className="greenput_narrow"
              onChange={e => {
                setUsername(e.target.value);
              }}
            />
            <br />
            <input
              type="password"
              name="password"
              className="greenput_narrow"
              onChange={e => {
                setPassword(e.target.value);
              }}
            />
            <br />
            <button className="greenput_narrow" type="submit">
              Login
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div className="IoLinks_outgoing">
          <h1>NullDisk</h1>
          <ul>
            <li>Military Grade Encryption</li>
            <li>Zettelkasten Schema</li>
            <li>VIM Keybindings</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Modal>
  );
}

Auth.defaultProps = defaultProps;
export default Auth;
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue here: in the input that you want to focus on put *autofocus*:

```html
 <input style={{width: "50%"}}maxLength="8" autoFocus value={inputValue} onChange={customTextChange.bind(this)} className={styles.patternSelector} />
```

You many want to conditionally add it based on an onChange event